# Technical Term for the Sum I + Q

Tags: complex, software-defined-radio

Most likely a very simple question, but I haven't been able to find a good answer.

When working with analytical signals in general, and software defined radio in particular, a common operation is to take the `sum real(z) + imag(z)`. Is there a technical term for this sum?

Comment: Must admit haven't seen that used very often!

Comment: Google "weaver modulator" for one example...

Comment: ah, to generate single side band, makes sense.

Comment: Exactly, but what is a good name for it? Trying to come up with a name for a libvolk kernel.

Comment: If this is for a VOLK kernel name: the complex numbers for these are just real and imaginary part one after another, so your operation is effectively `volk_32f_sum_pair_32f`, I'd say :)

Comment: I know the memory layout... But what is input vector length is odd, I'd like the input to be fc.

Comment: ```volk_32fc_add_real_imag_32f``` and ```volk_32fc_sub_real_imag_32f```?

Comment: ```volk_32fc_sum_parts_32f```?

Comment: We sadly don't mandate sanity anywhere, so, I don't really don't think there's a big downside to saying "this takes an even number of float pairs", but yeah, `volk_32fc_sum_parts_32f` does sound nice!

Answer (score 2):

This can be implemented, without needing to access the real and imaginary parts of $z$ individually, by writing

$$\operatorname{Re}(z) + \operatorname{Im}(z) = \frac{(1 + i)(z^* - iz)}{2},$$

where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $z^*$ is complex conjugation.

Factoring out a complex constant, $\xi = 1/2 + i/2$, turns this into a slightly tidier expression,

$$\operatorname{Re}(z) + \operatorname{Im}(z) = \xi(z^* - iz).$$

These expression can be derived by applying the [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry)

$$\cos(x) = \operatorname{Re}(e^{ix}) = \frac{{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}}{2}$$
$$\sin(x) = \operatorname{Im}(e^{ix}) = \frac{{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}}{2i}.$$

Perhaps this will give you some inspiration for choosing a good function name.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific term, as far as I know, but it's a very common operation with quadrature mixing. It's the result of taking the real part of an analytic signal.

You have a complex baseband signal $x(t)$, you modulate it with a complex carrier resulting in an analytic band pass signal, and then you take the real part to obtain the real-valued band pass signal that can be transmitted over a channel:

$$\begin{align}x(t)&=x_R(t)+j\cdot x_I(t)&\textrm{complex baseband signal}\\
y(t)&=x(t)e^{j\omega_ct}&\textrm{analytic band pass signal}\\
s(t)&=\textrm{Re}\{y(t)\}&\textrm{real-valued band pass signal}\\&=x_R(t)\cos(\omega_ct)-x_I(t)\sin(\omega_ct)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks Matt! Well this is what I'm doing... Just pondering what to name a SIMD optimized function I'm writing.

Comment: @AlbinStigo: Does the function just add real and imaginary parts, or does it also do the modulation?

Comment: result = real(z) + imag(z). For example f(2+5i)=7.

Comment: But $s(t)$ is neither the sum of the real and imaginary parts of $x(t)$ nor the sum of the real and imaginary parts of $e^{j\omega_ct}$ which sum would be $\cos \omega_ct + \sin\omega_ct$,  The $s(t)$ you show is actually the dot product of $[x_r(t), x_i(t)]$ and $[\cos\omega_ct, -\sin\omega_ct]$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: That's true, of course. But what appears to be the case is that the OP generates a complex signal $x_R(t)\cos(\omega_ct)-jx_I(t)\sin(\omega_ct)$, which, when adding its real and imaginary parts, results in the desired real-valued band pass signal.

Comment: And what would be a good name for a function that return re+imag? sum_parts()?

Answer (score 1):

After some thinking, I would could this a **cartesian sum**. It borrows from the notion of cartesian sum of two sets, here $\mathbb{R}$ (real part) and $i\mathbb{R}$ (imaginary part): if $x\in X$ and  $y\in Y$, the sum is the set of $x+y$.

This question initially sounded  odd to me, until I saw the recent Matlab code contest at MatlabCentral on this issue: [Problem 2554. Sum the real and imaginary parts of a complex number](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/problems/2554) (Last Solution submitted on May 12, 2020).
On SE Maths, there is a question on [Standard notation for sum of vector elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793856/standard-notation-for-sum-of-vector-elements).

So, complex numbers can be interpreted as vectors (but remember their algebraic structure is much richer). If a complex number $z=z_r+iz_i$ is written as $(z_r,z_i)$, and $\mathbb{I}=(1,1)$, then your sum writes $(z_r,z_i)\cdot\mathbb{I}^T =(z_r,z_i)^T\cdot\mathbb{I}$. The quantity can be translated into the complex scalar product, defined as:

$$ x.y = \frac{1}{2}(\overline{x}y+x\overline{y}).$$

Then, if $\mathbf{1}=1+i$ (an analog of $\mathbb{I}$), the sum of the real and imaginary parts is $z.\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{1}.z$. $\mathbf{1}=1+i$ is known as the smallest [Gaussian integer being a prime number, or Gaussian prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Gaussian_integer_factorizations#Factorizations). I don't know whether it has another name. Until then,  you could call it **ZdotI**.

Finally, [@Andy Walls](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/28112/andy-walls) was partly right in his answer: norms usually are non-negative, but some have defined [signed measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure). They are cumbersome to use, but if one wants a unique pedantic code, your can also  try **ComplexSignedDistance** to define this quantity. I have seen seldom cases of **Signed L1 norm**, but I would not recommend it.